# Incorrect image when switching from one camera to another on a marker?

Tags: camera, lighting, video, marker

Does someone know why I get a incorrect image when switching from one camera to another on a marker? I use Blender 3.4.

[image]

At frame 108 I switch from camera 'Cam Shot A' to 'Cam Shot B'. If I make a video and open it in davinci resolve the frame 108 shows an combination of Cam Shot A and the lighting of the scene 108. But Cam Shot B shoul already be active?

Additionally I tested it with a image sequence in Blender and there is also the incorrect image, but not if I render a single image. Why?

What goes wrong here?
Thanks...

Comment: Does not really seem to me to be a Blender issue, if everything is correct there. Have you checked it in Blender? Maybe rendered frame 108 as a still image? Or when rendering as an image sequence, on which frame number is the change? Which frame range have you set for your animation, starting at the default 1 or at 0? Because in DaVinci the first frame will be 0, no matter which start frame you have set in Blender, so the frame numbers in Blender's timeline are irrelevant for DaVinci.

Comment: Thxs! Yes I have checked it in Blender in Dope Sheet. There I can also sometimes observe it, if I manually move the slider from 107 to 108, but not always, and only for a short moment. But the single image rendered in Blender is correct. It seams so that blender mixes somehow theses images during creating a video because in davinci resolve I only check the single images. The range is about 300 and image 108 is somewhere between.

Comment: if you are using Blender 4.4 ...you are living in the far future....!

Comment: Thxs! Yeah, 4.4 would be really interesting :) Just changed it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found the reason. Responsible is the 'Disable' keyframe of the previous camera (A) at keyframe 108. If I remove it, the image is rendered correctly. But than I see all my cameras in all different shots in the viewport and that's annoying. Solution is, to only 'Disable Viewport' keyframe and leave out the 'Disable Renders' keyframe.

Nevertheless it seams so there is a bug in Blender 3.4. The single image is correctly rendered, the image sequence and video not.